# Applying properties of Legendre functions

Tags: legendre-polynomials

In addition to a former question.
I wish to show that:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^n P_n (x) dx = \frac{n}{2n+1}\int_{-1}^1 x^{n-1} P_{n-1} (x) dx$$

Assuming the result of:

$$P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1} = (2n+1)P_{n}$$

Multiplying both sides with $x^n$. We obtain:

$$x^nP'_{n+1}-x^nP'_{n-1} = x^n(2n+1)P_{n}$$

Now integrating both sides:

$$\int_{-1}^1x^nP'_{n+1}-x^nP'_{n-1}dx = \int_{-1}^1 x^n(2n+1)P_{n}dx$$

Now have to integrate by parts on the lefthand side. This becomes:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^n(P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1})dx= x^n[P_{n+1}-P_{n-1}]^{1}_{-1} - \int_{-1}^1 nx^{n-1}(P_{n+1}-P_{n-1})dx$$But here I am stuck. Any further help appreciated again.

Comment: Multiply your formula by $x^n$ and integrate over $[-1,1]$ using integration by parts on the left hand side. For the first integral note that $P_n$ is an even/odd function when $n$ is even/odd.

Comment: I tried to use your hint, and added it to the original question. But I am stuck halfway....

Comment: The first term $[\cdots]_{-1}^1$ is zero (since $P_n(1) = 1$ and $P_n(-1) = (-1)^n$) and using the relation $P_{n+1} = \frac{(2n+1)}{n+1}xP_n - \frac{n}{n+1}P_{n-1}$ on the $x^{n-1}P_{n+1}$ term gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By using [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula),
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!\space2^n}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n,
$$ one may integrate by parts $n$ times obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} x^{n}P_{n}(x) dx&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!\space2^n}\cdot n!\int_{-1}^{1} (x^2-1)^n dx
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^{1} u^{-1/2}(1-u)^n du
\end{align}
$$ that is, using the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) we have

> $$
> \int_{-1}^{1} x^{n}P_{n}(x) \:dx=\frac{2^n\:(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}.
> $$

Comment: So I don't have to use $P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1} = (2n+1)P_{n}$. Because the above result can be deduced by my statement which I wish to prove ie $\int_{-1}^1 x^n P_n (x) dx = \frac{n}{2n+1}\int_{-1}^1 x^{n-1} P_{n-1} (x) dx$